# Why is $A' + AB' + B$ always true?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I only know how to prove that $A'+AB'+B$ is always true with a truth table, but not boolean algebra. I haven't found  a suitable law to solve this.

A little guidance is much appreciated~

---

Edit: Thank you so much all for your answers! Really helped me understand more about how to use those laws.

I personally prefer the complement law approach, but the double-negative then De Morgan's is really useful too. Wish I could mark both of them helpful!

Comment: Hint: show that $A'+AB'=A'+B'$.

Comment: Wait a second, you're to use a truth table - isn't that just a table with columns A, B, A', B', AB', A'+AB'+B (and four rows) in this case? You don't need no law, just the truth tables / definitions of ◌', ◌◌, and ◌+◌.

Comment: @retzler I read it the other way. V C knows how to do it with a truth table, and asks how to do it with Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align} 
A'+AB'+B
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Since

\begin{align} 
A+A'=B+B'&=1
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

we can rewrite \eqref{1} as

\begin{align} 
&A'(B+B')+AB'+B(A+A')
\\
&=A'B+A'B'+AB'+AB
\tag{3}\label{3}
\\
&=A'(B+B')+A(B'+B)
\\
&=A'+A=1
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

You have $$AB^\prime = (AB^\prime)^{\prime \prime}=(A^\prime+B^{\prime \prime})^\prime = (A^\prime + B)^\prime$$ by double negation and de Morgan law and therefore

$$A^\prime+AB^\prime+B=(A^\prime+B) + AB^\prime = (A^\prime+B)+(A^\prime + B)^\prime = 1$$

Answer (score 6):

A hint: by de Morgan,

$$A'+AB'+B = (A(A'+B)B')'$$

Now see if the expression inside the outer parentheses simplifies.

Comment: Would this be the right continuation : $(AA'B'+ABB')'=0'=1 ?$

Comment: @sai-kartik Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an intuitive answer, make the substitution $C = A'$. Then the equation becomes

$$B + C + B'C'$$

which, in English, says that "Either B is true, C is true, or they're both false"